# Best way to handle similar classes and store them?

Tags: c#

**EDIT: This isn't the best approach for this problem. I managed to change design and use a List/Dictionary which creates a new instance of a class depending on the key selected. In this way you don't need any cast nor Reflection nor switch statement.**

I've a question that i tried to solve by myself but i'm not satisfied with my solutions. Let's set up a little example: i have a Farm class, a Mill class and a Bakery class. Those are buildings, and i'd like to store them in a list and obiouvsly i'd like to manage its elements whenever i need it. In this case this is a server-side code, and the list would need to have a list of all building of a player so i can send him that list whenever he requests it, for example when it joins. The player could build a Farm to start farming some wheat, then a Mill to start crushing it to make flour. Then he builds a Bakery to make some bread or pies. This is the example code:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public List<> Buildings = new List<>() //Or whatever solution to store them
}

public class Farm
{
    public string Name;
    public int CropType;
    public float Timer;
}

public class Mill
{
    public string Name;
    public float Timer;
}

public class Bakery
{
    public string Name;
    public int ProductionType;
    public bool IsOpen;
    public float Timer;
}
```

I've tried using Interfaces, abstract classes and normal classes to derive from but i haven't found my solution.

This is my try:

```cs
public interface IBuilding
    {
        string ExposedName { get; set; }
        string ExposedDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public class Farm : IBuilding
    {
        public string Name { get { return Name; } set { Name = value; } }
        public string Description { get { return Description; } set { Description = value; } }
        public int Crop;
    }

    public class Mill : IBuilding
    {
        public string Name { get { return Name; } set { Name = value; } }
        public string Description { get { return Description; } set { Description = value; } }
        public float Timer;
    }
```

I'd like to be able to access to each variable of each element of the List or whatever solution you suggest me without using non-performant code.

Comment: What was wrong with your interface or abstract class implementations?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?  I was going to suggest an interface, but it would be instructive to see where your attempt didn't work so we can provide guidance on how it *should* work.

Comment: All of those class members should really be turned into auto properties.

Comment: If you do use a base class or interface then you're likely going to break SOLID principals later on down the line. This all sounds a little like a code smell to me.

Comment: You can not expect to have a sort of list with items on wich you can call .CropType and .ProductionType without any cast.

Comment: Added my example but as you can see i can't access to each variable.

Comment: Your example is more a BaseClass than an Interface. Rename ExposedName to Name and ExposedDescription to Description. There is no need to dupplicate this in child classes.

Comment: If you need to access the distinct properties of the sub-class from outside the sub-class, you probably have a design problem.  Your buildings should have overridden methods on them that encapsulate their *distinct* behavior, while leaving the *common* behavior in the base.

Comment: Well, what about virtual and override? Is there a way to... use them to change the correct variables? Or, what's the design is should opt for?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Would you also say that WPF has a design problem because `Children` is an enumerable of different types of `Elements` with different properties? (And same for Winforms' `Children`)

Comment: @ispiro No, but that's because WPF and WinForms are *platform frameworks*, rather than implemented *applications*.  Also note, the other important word in my original comment, "probably".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheriting from a base class is the right way to do this. But when accessing elements from list, you should only use *interface of base class*. That means, only members of `Building` are allowed to use. Anything that relies on runtime type checking will work against you when you will add new buildings, because you must remember every place where it is to add a new case in switch.

Extract to base class only those members that can be called on any building, and implement them in derived classes.

You mentioned that you want not only to store them in a list, but also send to client (and probably receive). So I recommend to define `Building` such as this:

```
public abstract class Building : ISerializable, IDeserializable {
    // here you define interface, members which every building has
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract short Id { get; }
    public abstract void Update (); // do staff that this type of building does

    public abstract void ReadMembers (BinaryReader reader);
    public void Write (BinaryWriter writer) {
        writer.Write (Id);
        WriteMembers (writer);
    }
    public abstract void WriteMembers (BinaryWriter writer);
}
```

So, when you iterate through a list, you call methods from base class:

`foreach (var b in buildings) b.Update ();`

`foreach (var b in buildings) b.Write (writer);`

Reading is tricky. It requires writing an extension method for your reader, which should know about ids to create the right type of building.

```
public static class BinaryReaderExtension {

    private static Dictionary <short, Func <Building>> generators = new Dictionary <short, Func <Building>> ();


    static BinaryReaderExtension () {
        generators [0] = () => new Farm ();
        generators [1] = () => new Mill ();
    }


    public static Building ReadBuilding (this BinaryReader reader) {
        var b = generators [reader.ReadInt16 ()] ();
        b.ReadMembers (reader);
        return b;
    }

}
```

Important: `Id` must return unique number for each building, the same as in extension.

There is much room for experimenting.
You can use array instead of dictionary. You can write an extension for writer and remove `Id` and `Write` from `Building` class. You can use static method in `Building` returning `Building` instead of reader extension. You can also make such as this in `Building` class:

```
private Dictionary <Type, short> codeByType;
private Dictionary <short, Func <Building>> instanceByCode;
private void RegisterBuilding (Type t, short code) {
    // custom error checking for code to be unique, etc
}
```

and populate dictionaries from `Building` static initializer via this function.

Derived class should be defined such as:

```
public class Farm : Building {
    public override string Name => "Farm"; // assuming c# 6.0
    public override short Id => 0;

    private Crop crop;
    // other farm-specific things
    public override void Update {
        // you access a private field,
        // but Update method itself can be called even if you don't know the type
        // every building has its own implementation
        crop.Grow ();

        // other farm-specific things
    }

// override other methods, feel free to access private members of Farm here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't thought about a dictionary which creates a new class depending on the key!

Comment: @Penca53 I am glad to help. Can you upvote me then? (or accept answer if it solves your problem)

Comment: Well, i would like to upvote you but i can't because of my reputation that is below 15. I'll mark you as the correct answer but both of your answers, trollingchar and Scott are correct for me...

Comment: Just one more question: how can i access to a specific variable reading the Building class?

Comment: @Penca53 It should be in base class, declared as public. If you are overriding the behaviour in derived classes, you need an abstract property or method. If you want to access fields of a *derived* class, for example for writing to `BinaryStream`, or print info about building, generalize the goal and create an abstract method in base class and implement it in inheritors to achieve it. In my example, it's `WriteMembers` method.

Comment: @Penca53 I added an example of a derived class.

Comment: So I can only access to a base class variable, and I can't to a specific variable of the derived class @trollingchar

Comment: @Penca53 You can access that variable in implementation of base class's method or property in derived class. And when base class's method is called, the specific implementation runs and accesses the variable.

Comment: @trollingchar I know I'm late on that but would you see any downsides to changing the short to an Enum? You could even derive it from your desired type (short, byte, etc).

Comment: @Joelius Enums are based on int so they will be stored in 4 bytes. This is the only downside. You can explicitly make enum based on other integer type: `enum YourEnum : short {...}`.

Comment: @trollingchar Yea that's what I meant. I think this would be a bit nicer than just a plain short. Casting won't be a problem either since behind the scenes it's just the integer value. You could even use Attributes on the class (that you could do also with a short) or the enum-values to register them.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your try, but with an abstract class :

```
public abstract class Building
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Farm : Building
{
    public int Crop { get; set; }
}

public class Mill : Building
{
    public float Timer { get; set; }
}
```

Another part of the solution could be the IEnumerable possibilities (like OfType) to access to your properties of the items in your list in a loop. (Without "manual" casting nor ulgy "isXXX" code)

```
class MyCollection
{
    List<Building> buildings;

    public MyCollection()
    {
        buildings = new List<Building>();

        buildings.Add(new Farm() { Crop = 4 });
        buildings.Add(new Mill() { Timer = 4.5f });
        buildings.Add(new Farm() { Crop = 5 });
        buildings.Add(new Farm() { Crop = 6 });
        buildings.Add(new Mill() { Timer = 42 });
        buildings.Add(new Farm() { Crop = 55 });
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        foreach (Farm f in buildings.OfType<Farm>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.Crop);
        }

        foreach (Mill m in buildings.OfType<Mill>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Timer);
        }
    }
}
```

I Don't know if it's what you mean by

> "I'd like to be able to access to each variable of each element of the
>   List or whatever solution you suggest me without using non-performant
>   code."

Comment: Comparing to what ?

Comment: To interfaces and boxing

Comment: By adding a "IsXXX" function in the interface for each child class ? or IsType ? or by another way ? For boxing you need to know the type you want.

Comment: IsType compared to boxing, or isXXX.

Comment: If you were in me, how would you manage all the buildings of a client?

Comment: This seems ok only at first glance. `Print` should **NOT** do runtime type checking, it should be an abstract method in base class, implemented in derived classes. This code leaves Bulding, MyCollection and everything derived from Building entangled, and when you add new Building and forget to add a new loop here, it's a bug. With abstract method, compiler won't let you forget. And also it executes N times longer, when N is how many classes you have. And you should not even make a custom collection for this. I wonder why this answer has a positive score.

Answer (score 2):

In this description:

> The player could build a Farm to start farming some wheat, then a Mill to start crushing it to make flour. Then he builds a Bakery to make some bread or pies.

...you describe three different uses for three different classes.

In order to store a `Farm`, a `Mill`, and a `Bakery` in a list, they would need to have some common type. But that's really beside the point. They are three different classes that do different things, so if you're using them to farm, mill, and bake then there's no benefit whatsoever to putting them in a list with each other.

An interface or common class is only useful for describing what objects have or do in common, and using them in that context.

If you send a client a list of `Building`, the client only knows that they have descriptions and names. They can't know about the unique behaviors of different, more specific types of `Building`. They *shouldn't* know. That way if `Building` had a method like:

```
someBuilding.CloseDoors()
```

Then it would be possible to call that method on a building without knowing if it's a bakery, mill, etc. We don't care - we just want to close the doors. But if we want to `Bake` then we don't want a `Building`. We want a `Bakery`.

If you want to give the client objects that do distinctly different things then a list of one type of thing won't accomplish that.

The specifics of how to provide this functionality depend on your application. But here are some alternatives:

- Don't provide a list of something common. Provide instances or lists of something specific. Do you want to bake? Here are list of your bakeries. (The common `Name` and `Description` properties might make it easier to display a list of buildings in a reusable way.) Pick one and use it.
- Does the client actually need a list of bakeries, or just one? Maybe all they need is a `Bake` API method, and the available bakeries are managed behind the scenes.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the claryfing answer... i'll give you a quick example of the usage of a Bakery: client A clicks the bakery and asks the server the infos about that bakery. The server receives the request and gets the informations about that bakery, maybe using a unique ID, and sends them back to the client. The client receives those and updates the UI with, for instance, the Timer of the Baking process, the flour in it and the bread that is already cooked.

Comment: This is exactly what OP needs. Most of the other answers try to solve the case where he HAS to use this list and it isn't a surprise that these solutions aren't pretty nor good.

Comment: Then what you want might be something like `GetBakeryInformation(bakeryId)`. It returns a `Bakery`. That object has a `Name` and `Description` property which it inherits from `Building`. But because it's a `Bakery`, not just a `Building`, it also has other properties which are specific to `Bakery`.

Comment: I wanted to have the same class for each building because i didn't want to have a huuuge switch statement which checks the type of the class that the client receives (using an int). So, reading this, i think i've understood that i'll have to have a statement which will check the class that the client received (in this case, a mill or a farm or a bakery).

Comment: If you can avoid that switch it's best. Having a switch based on type or one based on an an `int` that signifies the type isn't that much different. Ideally you only want to call a method and get a `Building` if the only thing you care about the return value is that it's a `Building`. If you want a bakery then it would be better to ask for bakeries. If you get one or more `Bakery` then you can bake with it.

Comment: So, in the library i'm currently working on, I have messages which i can send over the network and each message has a tag. I could create a tag foreach type of building so i don't need a switch.

Comment: When we get into that it becomes a broader question because now we're not talking about giving clients classes. We're talking about giving them data, and that data could include describing available behaviors. At that point there should be a clear disconnect between the classes we use within our app and the data the client sees. Otherwise clients become coupled to the internal implementation of our application.

Comment: Well, because that library has a Serialize and Deserialize function which let's you serialize and deserialize a class.

Answer (score -2):

This is how i would set it up. You need to inherit from building, like others have mentioned. When running through the loop, just check if the building is a farm or bakery.

```
public abstract class Building
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Timer { get; set; }


}
public class Farm : Building
{
    public int CropType { get; set; }
    public Farm()
    {
    }
    public Farm(string name, int cropType, float timer)
    {
        Name = name;
        Timer = timer;
        CropType = cropType;
    }
}
public class Bakery : Building
{
    public int ProductionType { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
    public Bakery()
    {
    }
    public Bakery(string name, float timer, int prodType, bool isOpen)
    {
        Name = name;
        Timer = timer;
        ProductionType = prodType;
        IsOpen = isOpen;
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public static void myMethod()
    {
        Bakery bakery1 = new Bakery("Bake1", 123, 1, true);
        Farm farm1 = new Farm("Farm1", 2, 321);

        List<Building> buildings = new List<Building>();
        buildings.Add(bakery1);
        buildings.Add(farm1);

        foreach(Building building in buildings)
        {
            if(building is Farm)
            {
                Farm f1 = (Farm)building;
                int cropType = f1.CropType;
            }
            else if(building is Bakery)
            {
                Bakery b1 = (Bakery)building;
                int prodType = b1.ProductionType;
            }
        }
    }
}
```